# Doesn't a cache miss time overrule the time taken to directly access the data from ram

Tags: performance, caching, memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

Suppose there is a computer with three cache's L1,L2(inside the processor) and L3(external to the cpu) and a RAM. 
Now suppose CPU need to access data "ABC" for some operation which is definitely available in the RAM but due to the architecture- 
The CPU will first check for "ABC" inside L1 cache, where for instance it is not found(hence a cache miss --> some time wasted checking), 
then L2 cache is checked and again data is not found(again cache miss --> some time wasted), similarly L3 is checked and data is not found(cache miss --> some time wasted again),
 now finally RAM is checked where data is found and used.
 Now here isn't much time wasted just in checking various memories,   won't it be much more efficient to directly access the ram for such operations without checking any cache memory. 
**Keeping in mind that as the CPU progresses towards L2 from L1, L3 from L2, and RAM from L3 the physical distance of these memory units increase from the cpu and hence the access time.**

Comment: "L3(external to the cpu)" - not likely! External caches aren't really used nowadays.

Comment: No problem, we can consider the L3 also internal to the cpu :) .

Comment: If you had a CPU with caches that were that slow to check (unlikely), you'd design it to probe multiple levels of cache in parallel with sending the request to the memory controller.  And maybe design a mechanism to squash those requests if a hit arrives before you get to RAM.  But the #1 rule of caching is that caches work!  Hits are common.  In a typical Skylake-desktop CPU, the extra latency for a cache miss that has to go all the way to DRAM is maybe an extra 20 cycles spent just checking caches on the way down the memory hierarchy, out of >= 250 cycles for DRAM.  Hits make it worth it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think it in reverse way, if data found in L1 then it will save comparatively more time than in RAM same is case with L2 and L3. As Harold pointed out L3 is not external to CPU nowadays.

In terms of size L1 < L2 < L3 <<< RAM

This shows searching in RAM will take much more time than searching in L* caches. Caches were introduced for this purpose i.e. To save search time.

As you said, sometimes yes if data is not present in L1,L2,L3 then you need to access RAM with some penalty of caches but that data will be saved in cache for future access. Thus advantages of having cache hits outweighs this penalty.

Generally cache hit ratio should be/ is 90%, if it is not then you need to tune caching policy.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes it was. Also I'd like to know dies physical distance really matter in terms of data transfer since electrical signal speed is comparable to the speed of light.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. For your question answer is No. That should be very small (negligible). Important thing here is you save all those instructions (search in L1, search in L2, search in L3, search in RAM) if you find data as fast as possible. complexity increases from L1 to RAM. I would appreciate if you accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Surely :) . Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 DRAM is slow because DRAM cells are inherently slow and the interface isn't that fast either, the "distance" people speak of usually means "distance in time" - though it also corresponds to physical distance, it not primarily caused by it.

Comment: @harold what is "distance in time" ?

Comment: @harold what is "distance in time" ?

Comment: what he meant by "distance in time" is, time reqd to access one cell/unit of dram/L1/L2/L3 is considered as distance (which is proportional to physical distance, speed of dram etc.). @harold correct if you meant something else.

Comment: Sorry but I am still unable to understand it .

Comment: To avoid long tail of comments, please join chat room named 'Q34585816'. @harold, you are also invited to join

Comment: "Further from the CPU" is jargon for "takes more time to access", the physical distance does not contribute much to that time but correlates with it anyway (you wouldn't put a harddisk in your CPU, it wouldn't help if you did).

Comment: How do I join this chat room ?